# Почему удаляются куки?

Tags: php

Пишу сайт с авторизацией на php? Устанавливаю куки с помощью

```
setcookie('pass',md5(md5($pwd)));
setcookie('uid',mysql_insert_id());
```

При переходе по страницам браузера куки не удаляются, но если закрыть страницу и браузер куки исчезают.
С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Время жизни куки заканчивается когда Вы закрываете браузер.

Добавьте третий параметр в функцию setcookie. Оно принимает целые числа в секундах.

Comment: > Оно принимает целые числа. 1 = одному
> дню и т.д.

[Разве?][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Ошибочка))) там время в секундах оказывается)))) Просто я переделал для себя функцию немного, чтоб она принимала только дни, поэтому зацыклился.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай , Вы переписали php-ишную либу ради дней в куках? О_О я верно понял? :)

Comment: Та неее... просто написал функцию.

Answer (score 1):

int setcookie (string name [, string value [, int expire [, string path [, string domain [, int secure]]]]])

пример, с использованием всех аргументов:

setcookie ("TestCookie", $value,time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", ".utoronto.ca", 1);

+3600 = 1 час